# Configure Android black box

Tags: 7.0-nougat, debug

My apps on my phone keep bugging out on me, but I can never catch them in the act. Is there any way to keep a black box of my phone state (perhaps polled every 1 minute) for the past x minutes so that when I catch a bug, I can save the last x minutes and debug them later?

Answer (score 0):

Run a system monitoring app, then go back through the morning log until you find it. This is just an idea which helped me with data consumption on new Sprint Pro hotspot which should have not been released yet.

Comment: It would be better if you could also provide a link to the "system monitoring app" you mentioned.